# Opposite of INTERSECT in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two selects and I want to combine them in such a way, that only rows unique in both selects are returned. Is there any built-in way in Oracle 10g to achieve this?

I know I can do something like this:

```
(select1 UNION select2)
MINUS
(select1 INTERSECT select2)
```

but I would like to avoid it. Both `select1` and `select2` have 20 lines, so this way would be really obscure and difficult to maintain.

Comment: The name of this operator is 'symmetric difference' - with this, google gives a number of results (wich all tend to suggest this isn't going to be fast).

Comment: It is not a problem for me if this is slow. This is a batch script for my personal use, no need for it to be super efficient.

Comment: How do the two selects look like? It might be possible to modify them, so that you run only one select and get the final result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If both `select1` and `select2` return no duplicates, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (select1 UNION ALL select2) a
GROUP BY a.col1, a.col2, ...
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle 10g, you've got Common Table Expressions at your disposal.

```
WITH
  select_1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM your_table
    WHERE your_condition = 1
  ),
  select_2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM your_other_table
    WHERE your_other_condition = 1
  )
SELECT * FROM select_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM select_2
MINUS
(
  SELECT * FROM select_1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT * FROM select_2
);
```

This keeps your subqueries maintainable and the purpose of your final query clear.

Of course, having Oracle add a `SYM_DIFFERENCE` operator to SQL would be even better, but I'm not holding my breath — they're still not convinced a `BOOLEAN` datatype would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idea:

- Do a full outer join of select1 and select2
- Use only those records with select1.id = NULL (record is only in select2) or select2.ID = NULL (record is only in select1)

like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM select1 FULL OUTER JOIN select2 on select1.id = select2.id
WHERE select1.id is null or select2.id is null
```

Comment: I find this answer as the best - with this approach other data then the ids can be select within one effective query.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me- not sure how fast it is.

```
(select table_name from dba_tables where user = 'X'
union
select table_name from dba_tables where user = 'Y')
minus
(select table_name from dba_tables where user = 'X'
intersect
select table_name from dba_tables where user = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- get not intersect data
SELECT_FINAL
WHERE FIELD_PK IS NOT IN(
    -- get ids of intersect
    SELECT_AUX FIELD_PK1 FROM (
        SELECT1
        INTERSECT
        SELECT2
     )
)
```

i do it

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, this time using the count() analytic (Oracle 10 or later).

Advantages:

- we can specify which columns to EXTRASECT on (e.g. KK1, KK2 in the example).
- we can select non-key columns (e.g. NK1, NK2... in the example) which we don't require to match.
- efficient plan.
- Similar to the FULL OUTER JOIN example, but we don't get the key columns as separate fields needing decode or case to fold them together.

`select KK1, KK2, NK1, NK2
   from ( select KK1, 
                 KK2, 
                 NK1, 
                 NK2, 
                 count( * ) over( partition by KK1, KK2 ) cnt 
            from ( select KK1, KK2, NK1, NK2 from X
                    union all
                   select KK1, KK2, NK1, NK2 from Y ) )
  where cnt = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 dataset
Table1
ID Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
7  D

Table2
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
4   E
6   F
(select * from table1
minus
select * from table2)
Union
(select * from table2
minus
select * from table1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).